# How can i do migrations folder in class library?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have class library in my solution with my database models and DbContext. I want to add migrations in this layer but get error.

I use this command:
`dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`

but after running have this error

> No DbContext was found in assembly 'DRM.Repo'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.

Comment: Is DRM.Repo the correct project? Is that the class library where you defined your DbContext?

Comment: Is the DbContext in the same project? And is it complete? Do you have a reference to the database in it?

Comment: yes it was same project thank you for soon reply i have found resolved  way i wrote on command this "add-migration initial -verbose" and it works...

Answer (score 1):

Resolved way: 
1)open Tools >> Nuget Package Manager >> package manager console 
2)ensure that default project in dropdown is where you want to create your migrations and run this code "add-migration initial -verbose"